# ¿Cómo aplicar dict.fromkeys a sublistas?

Tags: python-3.x

Buenas tardes a todos,

Estoy utilizando la funcion dict.fromkeys para obtener los elementos no repetidos de una lista.
El **problema** es que no funciona cuando se intenta obtener el mismo resultado de un input formado por sublistas

```
def unique(lst):

orden = list(dict.fromkeys(lst))

return orden
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se me ocurre cómo hacer

Comment: La llave de un diccionario tiene que se *hashable*; las listas no son *hashables*. No puedes usar una lista como llave.

Comment: Tienes que plantear el problema completo: ¿cual lista de listas? ¿Quieres eliminar las sublistas repetidas? Please, datos de entrada y resultado esperado.

Comment: El problema me pide que escriba una función que reciba una lista formada por objetos de cualquier tipo y devuelva otra lista con los elementos únicos.  A mayores, en el mismo orden en que aparecían en la lista original. Los datos de entrada yo no los se hasta que se hace el precheck

Comment: @Candid Moe entiendo que la cuestión es hacer las llaves hashables para poder aplicar dict.fromkeys

Comment: prueba con [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in lst)] para los arreglos de listas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución:

```
def unicos(lista):
    uni = []
    for x in lista:
        if x not in uni:
            uni.append(x)
    return uni
```

La función recibe una lista de objetos arbitrarios. La recorre colocando en la salida cada elemento de la lista, siempre que este no esté ya presente.

#### Demo

```
lista = lista = [1, 2, 2, "hola", "hola", [1, 2], [1, 2], {1: "hola"}, {1: "hola"}]

uni = unicos(lista)
print(uni)
```

produce:

```
[1, 2, 'hola', [1, 2], {1: 'hola'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Increíble, como siempre. Qué elegancia y visión. Muchas gracias, amigo.